# Unknown SSE bottleneck

Tags: optimization, floating-point, x86, sse, simd

I have a generic code that I am trying to move to SSE to speed it up since it's getting called a lot. The code in question is basically something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < mysize; ++i)
{
    buf[i] = myMin(buf[i], buf[i - 1] + offset);
}
```

where myMin is your simple min function (a < b) ? a : b (I've looked at the disassembly and there are jumps in here)

My SSE code (which I've gone through several iterations to speed up) is at this form now:

```
float tmpf = *(tmp - 1);
__m128 off = _mm_set_ss(offset);
for (int l = 0; l < mysize; l += 4)
{
    __m128 post = _mm_load_ps(tmp);
    __m128 pre = _mm_move_ss(post, _mm_set_ss(tmpf));
    pre = _mm_shuffle_ps(pre, pre, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 3, 2, 1));
    pre = _mm_add_ss(pre, off);
    post = _mm_min_ss(post, pre);

    // reversed
    pre = _mm_shuffle_ps(post, post, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 1, 0, 3));
    post = _mm_add_ss(post, off );
    pre = _mm_min_ss(pre, post);

    post = _mm_shuffle_ps(pre, pre, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 1, 0, 3));
    pre = _mm_add_ss(pre, off);
    post = _mm_min_ss(post, pre);

    // reversed
    pre = _mm_shuffle_ps(post, post, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 1, 0, 3));
    post = _mm_add_ss(post, off);
    pre = _mm_min_ss(pre, post);

    post = _mm_shuffle_ps(pre, pre, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 1, 0, 3));
    _mm_store_ps(tmp, post);
    tmpf = tmp[3];
    tmp += 4;
}
```

Ignoring any edge case scenarios, which I've handled fine, and overhead for those are negligible due to size of buf/tmp, can anyone explain why the SSE version is slower by 2x? VTune keeps attributing it to L1 misses, but as I can see, it should be make 4x less trips to L1 and no branches/jumps, so it **should** be faster, but it's not. What am I mistaking here?

Thanks

EDIT: 
So I did find something else in a separate test case. I didn't think this would matter but alas it did. So mysize above is actually not that big (about 30-50), but there are a LOT of these and they are all being done serially. In that case, the ternary expression is faster than SSE. However, if it's reversed with mysize being in millions and there are only 30-50 iterations of them, the SSE version is faster. Any idea why? I would think memory interactions would be the same for both, including pre-emptive prefetching etc...

Comment: Is the SSE version actually any more parallel than the original?

Comment: The serial dependency is what's killing you here - it makes the loop unsuitable for SIMD vectorization and you're doing a lot of work in the SIMD loop as a result. It would probably be more productive to focus on optimising the scalar loop: make sure you are using a branchless min without any unnecessary float<->double conversions and perhaps also unroll the loop manually (being careful about the dependencies of course).

Comment: The profiler is wrong. That loop isn't vectorizable - unless you try something like a parallel prefix min.

Comment: If you knew that `buf[i]` was less than `buf[i-1]` most of the time then you could probably use `_mm_movemask_epi8` to speed this up.

Comment: Thanks for replies. The values can be anything. About branchless min, I have been unsuccessful with that as well. I am doing this on x64 and the simple ternary expression above doesn't compile to a branchless min, there are jumps in the compiled code (VS2010). Any suggestions how to force it to to branchless on x64?

Comment: Can you post the code you're currently using for `myMin` ? It would be good to find a way to make your compiler use `FCMOV` rather than having to resort to assembler. (Or you could switch to a better compiler!)

Comment: @PaulR, would'nt `minss` be a better choice than `fcmov`?

Comment: @Zboson: it might be, particularly on newer CPUs - it would be good to try both methods and see. It would also be interesting to see what a decent compiler (gcc, clang, ICC) generates for a single precision min operation.

Comment: @PaulR myMin is a simple ternary compare return (a < b) ? a : b

Comment: @user1181950: sure - but is it a macro, an inline function, a template function, or what ? It would be useful to see the actual code.

Comment: Sorry it's inline function:
static inline float myMin(const float &a, const float& b)
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
I've also tried replacing it directly in the profiling function without a function call (even though it's inline) but get same timing data.

Comment: @user1181950: I just tried to profile your code out of interest, but the output doesn't seem to match for the scalar and SIMD implementations. I'm wondering if there's a mistake, perhaps in the scalar code (maybe you typed it from memory) ?

Answer (score 1):

If this code is performance critical, you'll have to look at the data that you get. It's the serial dependency that's killing you, and you need to get rid of it.

One very small value an buf [i] will influence a lot of the following values. For example, if offset = 1, buf [0] = 0, and all other values are > 1 million, that one value will influence the next one million. On the other hand, that kind of thing might happen very rarely.

If it is rare, they you check fully vectorised whether buf [i] > buf [i] + offset, replace it if it is, and keep track where changes were made, without considering that buf [i] values could trickle upwards. Then you check where changes were made, and re-check them.

In extreme cases, say buf [i] is always between 0 and 1, and offset > 0.5, you know that buf [i] cannot influence buf [i + 2] at all, so you just ignore the serial dependency and do everything in parallel, fully vectorised.

On the other hand, if you have some tiny values in your buffer that influence large numbers of consecutive values, then you start with the first value buf [0] and fully vectorised check whether buf [i] < buf [0] + i * offset, replacing values, until the check fails.

You say "the values can be anything". If that is the case, for example if buf [i] is randomly chosen anywhere between 0 and 1,000,000, and offset is not very large, then you will have elements buf [i] which force lots of following elements to be buf [i] + (k - i) * offset. For example if offset = 1, and you find buf [i] is about 10,000, then it will force on average about 100 values to be equal to buf [i] + (k - i) * offset.

Comment: Your answer can be summed up with my comment "If you knew that buf[i] was less than buf[i-1] most of the time then you could probably use _mm_movemask_epi8 to speed this up" and the OP replied "The values can be anything." which I infer means that he can't assume anything about the statistics of the distribution.

Comment: The idea is to ignore dependencies completely, so you get fully vectorised code - and then fix up the bits where you went wrong. Not being able to assume anything about the distribution of the values is a copout. The current code is basically scalar _and_ has dependencies. Vectorising makes it probably 10 times faster, and that requires looking at the data.

Comment: Then post some code showing how to do this. I doubt it will help for random data. In fact I think it could be worse to assume no dependency then correct for random data. I guess an intelligent method could monitor the statistics as it went along and if it found the data was not very random could assume the data was not random. In that case I could see a benefit but that's work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a branchless solution you could try

```
for (int i = 1; i < mysize; i++) {
    float a = buf[i];
    float b = buf[i-1] + offset;
    buf[i] = b + (a<b)*(a-b);
}
```

Here is the assembly:

```
.L6:
addss   xmm0, xmm4
movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax]
movaps  xmm2, xmm1
add rax, 4
movaps  xmm3, xmm6
cmpltss xmm2, xmm0
subss   xmm1, xmm0
andps   xmm3, xmm2
andnps  xmm2, xmm5
orps    xmm2, xmm3
mulss   xmm1, xmm2
addss   xmm0, xmm1
movss   DWORD PTR [rax-4], xmm0
cmp rax, rdx
jne .L6
```

But the version with a branch is probably already better

```
for (int i = 1; i < mysize; i++) {
     float a = buf[i];
     float b = buf[i-1] + offset;
     buf[i] = a<b ? a : b;
}
```

Here is the assembly

```
.L15:
addss   xmm0, xmm2
movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax]
add rax, 4
minss   xmm1, xmm0
movss   DWORD PTR [rax-4], xmm1
cmp rax, rdx
movaps  xmm0, xmm1
jne .L15
```

This produces code which is branchless anyway using `minss` (`cmp rax, rdx` applies to the loop iterator).

Finally, here is code you can be used with MSVC which produces the same assembly as GCC which is branchless

```
__m128 offset4 = _mm_set1_ps(offset);
for (int i = 1; i < mysize; i++) {
    __m128 a = _mm_load_ss(&buf[i]);
    __m128 b = _mm_load_ss(&buf[i-1]);
    b = _mm_add_ss(b, offset4);
    a = _mm_min_ss(a,b);
    _mm_store_ss(&buf[i], a);
}
```

Here is another form you can try which uses a branch

```
__m128 offset4 = _mm_set1_ps(offset);
for (int i = 1; i < mysize; i++) {
    __m128 a = _mm_load_ss(&buf[i]);
    __m128 b = _mm_load_ss(&buf[i-1]);
    b = _mm_add_ss(b, offset4);
    if(_mm_comige_ss(b,a))
        _mm_store_ss(&buf[i], b);
}
```

Comment: Although this is branchless, it uses way more instructions than needed. Ideally for x86 you would want to exploit `FCMOV`.

Comment: @PaulR, I see your point. I updated my answer. The version with a branch is probably already good enough (and better). It does not really have a branch since it uses `minss`. If I compile in 32-bit mode I get `fcmov` but I don't think that's a good idea. It's probably best to use `minss`.

Comment: I think the main problem is that the OP is using Visual Studio and this is generating branchy code. gcc et al are already smart enough to generate branchless code without any additional help.

Comment: @PaulR, yeah, GCC out smarted me here. Though I would have figured it out because I would have profiled my function and found it was worse.

Comment: @PaulR, I added code to the end of my answer which uses intrinsics to do the same thing as GCC which can be used with MSVC.

Comment: cool - it would be interesting to benchmark the various implementations on a modern CPU and see which is fastest. I'm guessing for large data sets it will be somewhat memory bandwidth limited, but for smaller data sets in cache then it should be easy to see which is fastest.

Comment: @Zboson I actually have the original myMin code which is a simple ternary expression, then I had this before
    _mm_store_ss(&ret, _mm_min_ss(_mm_set_ss(a), _mm_set_ss(b)));
which was profiled to be slower than the branching ternary expression which I profiled and found L1 be bottleneck. I then kept changing till the code in the original post which is 2x faster than the code a few lines above, but still 2x slower than the ternary

Comment: @user1181950, the last code I posted to my answer using intrinsics produces almost the exact same assembly that GCC produces using the ternary operator. I doubt MSVC's implementation of the ternary operator is better. Can you please post the assembly output for this function to your question.

Comment: movss       xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rdx*4-4]  
movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rdi+rdx*4]  
addss       xmm0,xmm6  
comiss      xmm1,xmm0  
jb          main+287h (013F1A1287h)  
movaps      xmm1,xmm0  
movss       dword ptr [rdi+rdx*4],xmm1 

Also I posted an EDIT with a little more info I found.

Comment: ugh I hate these lack of newlines :(

Comment: @user1181950, okay, you could have added this to your question instead of the comments here. To be clear. This is the MSVC's implementation of the ternary operator?

Comment: @user1181950, I updated my answer again and added new code you can try using the `comiss` instruction from the MSVC assembly.

Comment: @PaulR, MSVC appears to be using `_mm_comige_ss` from the assembly the OP posted in my comments above. I edited my answer with a version using `comiss`.

Comment: @Zboson: OK - so it was branchless already then - maybe the OP was looking at a version from a debug build previously, or something like that.

Comment: @PaulR, no, it has a branch. It writes to the array if _mm_comige_ss(b,a) otherwise it does not write the array. See the end of my answer.

Comment: Oh yes - I missed that first time around when I was looking at the code in the comment above.